# slow ftp session

Tags: linux, iptables, unix, ftp

I am running ProFTPD Version 1.3.3c in active ftp mode and have the following firewall rules.

But whenever, I do directory listing, it is too slow. It takes time, but directory and files get listed.

As soon as I flush iptables rule, then it is fast. What I am missing in this rule ?

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:21 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using passive FTP? If so you need to also open up a range of ports above 1023. It doesn't really matter which ports, but commonly 2000-3000 are used.

As a test if this is your problem, set your FTP client to ACTIVE (or whatever it names the opposite choice is PASSIVE) and see if you still have the same problem. If not, then you need to open some high ports to allow the passive stuff to happen.

Comment: Here's a good synopsis of the PASSIVE issue and firewalls.

http://www.ncftp.com/ncftpd/doc/misc/ftp_and_firewalls.html#PASVFirewallProblems

Comment: He says right in the question that they're using active mode.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to open port TCP 20 for the data socket. [link](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch4.html#AEN284)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, FTP has to be the worse protocol still in use. If at all possible you should use SSH instead.

Active FTP requires port 20 to be open ON THE CLIENT. This is clearly impossible in most cases and breaks all the rules of sane behaviour and firewall configuration. This is why most people just use passive FTP, which requires a range of high-numbered ports open on the server, in addition to port 21.

This site has more explanation, and some helpful diagrams:
http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html